# Laravel - route within view isn't working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm learning laravel, working with 3 files, `Welcome.blade.php` / `route.php` / `tryaction.php` and it's a controller.

I made three links that fetched from database table => hug, greet and slap

when I click any link it gives me an error that **actions** is not defined.

my `Welcome.blade.php`:

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($actions as $action)
        <li><a href="{{ route('benice', ['action' => $action->name]) }}">{{$action->name}}</a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

my `route.php`:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', [
    'uses'      => 'tryaction@getHome',
]);

//to deal with get requests
Route::get('/{action}/{name?}', [
    'uses'      => 'tryaction@doget',
    'as'            => 'benice'
]);
```

my `tryaction.php` controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\actionstable;

class tryaction extends Controller
{
    public function doget($action, $name = null){
            return view('actions.'.$action,['name'=>$name]);
        }

        public function getHome(){
            $actions = actionstable::all();
            return view('welcome',['actions'=>$actions]);
        }
}
```

when I replace the `href` route in `welcome.blade.php` with `#` instead of `{{ route('benice', ['action' => $action->name]) }}` the error stops from showing on

the data are fetched correctly and the data is shown on the page .. the problem in the route and it's that the **actions** is not defined, here is the error page:

[image: Error page]

Comment: Check $actions that you are using in the for loop..

Comment: I checked before and it's giving results and shows the name of action

Comment: PHP does not think that `$actions` is defined in that view.

Comment: Laravel has a great helper function that can be used to diagnose the issue: `dd()` which stands for `die and dump`. In your blade, before your iteration over `$actions`, try adding `{{ dd($actions) }}` to see what is displayed. This is a quick way to confirm what information is in `$actions` since your error is stating it is undefined.

Comment: @camelCase I used it and it gave me results .. array of objects that i need

Comment: Well if `$actions` is returning data, but your error is stating that it is undefined, then I'm not sure. It should be working according to what information we have. I notice you have `Welcome.blade.php` capitalized here but in your error it is lowercase...I believe in Linux this will cause an issue, but not in windows. Just a thought. Also, perhaps try `composer update` since you're just in a dev site, otherwise `composer install` for production sites.

Comment: Wait, do you call `$actions` in your `hug.blade.php` view? Because line 4 references this blade so perhaps the issue is within that blade?

Comment: no I don't call it .. here is my `hug.blade.php` same as `kiss` and `slap` :

`@extends('welcome')

@section('content')
  <h1>I Hug {{$name? $name : 'you'}}</h1>
@endsection`